# Does any of you encountered this kind of problem from vbnet 2010 - NET.MAIL situation? How can I resolve this? Thank you, Developers

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail-imap

I get this error trying to send a message in VB.Net via Gmail:

[image]

after attempting to send a message, my google account in device/website has logged out and asking for verification for unusual activity (which is sending message in vbnet 2010).

This is my source code  ↓ ↓ ↓

```vb
Try

    Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()

    smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(emailFrom, passW)
    smtpserver.Port = 465 ' 587 alternate
    smtpserver.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpserver.EnableSsl = True

    mail = New MailMessage()
    mail.From = New MailAddress(emailFrom)
    mail.To.Add(emailTo)
    mail.Subject = "Subject"
    mail.Body = "hello 2024"

    smtpserver.Send(mail)
    MsgBox("Mail Sent")

Catch ex As Exception

    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Close()

End Try
```

Is it possible because of 2nd-authentication of the Gmail account?
how can I possibly resolve this?

Comment: Gmail no longer supports basic username/password auth. You have to do OAuth "modern" authentication. There is an option for a per-app password or "less secure app", but this is also in the sunset phase and will be [disabled by October](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)... hardly makes sense to do new work for it now.

Comment: Yeah. I just figured out using Visual Studio 2022. Maybe I need particular libraries attachment for VS 2010 Visual Basic

Comment: Doesn't matter what version of Visual Studio you have... gmail just won't let you do this any more no matter what you use.